# jQuery on binding gets removed, live doesn't

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.8.0 to bind an `onchange` event to an `<input type="file">` element. In my page I have a clear button to clear the input.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="upload" type="file">
</div>
<button id="button">clear</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id='upload']").on("change",
        function()
        {
            alert('changed');
        });
    $("[id='button']").click(
        function()
        {
            $("[id='wrapper']").html($("[id='wrapper']").html());
        });
</script>
```

When I select a file for the first time the alert shows. However when I clear the input using the button the alert doesn't work anymore.

To demonstrate the problem I've created a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/etowev/1/).

When using the `.live` binding instead of the `.on` binding it works flawlessly, but I noticed that the `.live` method is deprecated. So what to use instead?

Comment: `[id='button']` === `#button`.

Comment: @alex I know, I use `[id='']` to escape some characters that may appear in the generated HTML. (I'm using JSF, but that isn't relevant) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`live` delegates the event from document object, but `on` doesn't, using `on` you should delegate the event from one of static parents of the element or document object.

> `live` method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page.

```
$('#wrapper').on("change", "#upload", function() {
     alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you serialise the HTML to replace it with other HTML, you lose bound events (there is no place in the string to mark the reference).

You can use `on()` with a common non mutated ancestor. However, the body of your function doesn't make a huge amount of sense. You're replacing the contents with the same HTML, so the only benefit you get is you lose by default all non serialisable to HTML data.

```
$("#upload").on("change",
        function()
        {
            alert('changed');
        });

$("#button").click(
        function()
        {
            // Something.
        });
```

I've also changed your selectors to make them easier to comprehend.

Comment: That's what I thought, however the `.live` method works. Should I keep on using the `.live` method regardless that it's deprecated?

Comment: If you're using a version that has deprecated it, you could use `on()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point. `on()` doesn't work In my example because I 'reset' the `input`.

Comment: @siebz0r See where I wrote *common non mutated ancestor*.  That could be `body` in your example, but you didn't provide enough context to accurately tell (though `body` will work anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation +1. The answer @undefined posted works using a common ancestor so I accepted that answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$.live()` is deprecated partly because people didn't understand how it worked. If I were you I'd go with `$.on()` and do the following:

```
var onChange = function () {
    alert('changed');
};

$("[id='upload']").on("change", onChange);

$("[id='button']").click( function() {
    $("[id='wrapper']").empty().append(
        $("<input/>")
            .prop("type", "file")
            .prop("id", "upload")
            .change(onChange)
    );
});
```